# How i can align correctly my navbar items (ul)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsive

I need some help with the alignment in the bootstrap navbar, I want to rectify this with only bootstrap classes if its possible.

My current design of navbar, works properly in responsive(lg-expand) when the hamburger appears my alignment is ok, the icons and hamburger at right, and the rest of content downside,

But when my navbar is in full width, I need that icons and user to be above the list items ( aligned in right side)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.9.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" integrity="sha512-vIgFb4o1CL8iMGoIF7cYiEVFrel13k/BkTGvs0hGfVnlbV6XjAA0M0oEHdWqGdAVRTDID3vIZPOHmKdrMAUChA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://soporte.isyc.com/static/202004211417/theme/images/branding/portal_logo_core.png" /></a>
  <div class="float-right">
  <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle info pr-2 text-primary font-size-19"></i><a href="#" class="text-primary"><span class="pr-3 border-right border-primary font-size-14">jardeleanu</span></a><a href="/logout" class="pt-1"><i class="pl-3 pr-3 mdi mdi-power text-primary font-size-22"></i></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button></div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My design when is full width, i would like to be like this :  https://ibb.co/Gntcpk5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.9.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" integrity="sha512-vIgFb4o1CL8iMGoIF7cYiEVFrel13k/BkTGvs0hGfVnlbV6XjAA0M0oEHdWqGdAVRTDID3vIZPOHmKdrMAUChA==" crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex">
        <div class="col-8">

            <a class="navbar-brand " href="#"><img src="https://soporte.isyc.com/static/202004211417/theme/images/branding/portal_logo_core.png" /></a>


        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 25%;">
                <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle info pr-2 text-primary font-size-19 "></i><a href="#" class="text-primary"><span
                        class="pr-3 border-right border-primary font-size-14">jardeleanu</span></a>
                <a href="/logout" class="pt-1"><i class="pl-3 pr-3 mdi mdi-power text-primary font-size-22"></i></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

can check at:https://jsfiddle.net/y19drx5j/1/

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented it with bootstrap classes.

> While testing, you can click on the "full screen" link in the upper right corner.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.9.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" integrity="sha512-vIgFb4o1CL8iMGoIF7cYiEVFrel13k/BkTGvs0hGfVnlbV6XjAA0M0oEHdWqGdAVRTDID3vIZPOHmKdrMAUChA==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex flex-wrap">
      <a class="navbar-brand order-lg-2" href="#"><img src="https://soporte.isyc.com/static/202004211417/theme/images/branding/portal_logo_core.png" /></a>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center ml-lg-auto">
        <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle info pr-2 text-primary font-size-19"></i><a href="#" class="text-primary"><span class="pr-3 border-right border-primary font-size-14">jardeleanu</span></a><a href="/logout" class="pt-1"><i class="pl-3 pr-3 mdi mdi-power text-primary font-size-22"></i></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button></div>
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block"></div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end order-lg-3" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**What has changed**

- `<div class="float-right">` element class changed to `"d-flex align-items-center ml-lg-auto"`
- Element `<div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block"></div>` added.
- `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex">` element class list added to `flex-wrap`.
- `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">` class added `order-lg-2`.
- `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" ...`  element class list add `order-lg-3`.